# "ERROR: could not access status of transaction Could not open file "pg_xact/0029": No such file or directory" when attempting to LISTEN

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

When attempting to `LISTEN` to any channel, PostgreSQL says that `Could not open file "pg_xact/0029": No such file or directory.`

This is a freshly restored database, so it can't be database corruption.

Changing to another database `/c anotherdb` works, restarting the PostgreSQL instance also fixes the issue. The issue seems to appear randomly after a few days of uptime.

```
loritta=# LISTEN abc;
ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 43350785
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_xact/0029": No such file or directory.
```

**PostgreSQL Version:** PostgreSQL 15.2

Comment: I do have an theory about what happened: I had a stuck query for ~7 days, this caused the auto vacuum to run, and that cleaned up files on the `pg_xact` folder

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? I have a [similar problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333186/error-could-not-access-status-of-transaction-sqlstate-58p01-when-calling-list?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have to restart Postgres as well to recover.

Comment: Sadly I haven't @user2233706, also it doesn't seem that your issue is similar to mine: Yours happens right after boot randomly, mine happens after X days after the PostgreSQL instance is up

Comment: I've better characterized my problem. My issue also happens if we run the application and database for long time, such as least a day. I think we have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you commented, this is very likely the problem described in [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/VE1PR03MB531295B1BDCFE422441B15FD92499%40VE1PR03MB5312.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com#7e36d1fdca921b5292e92c7017984ffa).  In that case, the solution would be to avoid very long running transactions in the session that listens. Notifications are not delivered while you are inside a transaction, and by the time the transaction is done, the transaction ID associated with the notification might not exist any more.

Comment: This happened in a freshly restored database, in fact, this was freshly restored (from a `pg_dump` .sql file) BECAUSE the previous database exhibited the same bug so I thought it was corruption.

There's a thread on the PSQL group that someone reported something similar, while the user that reported this doesn't have the same issue, the explanation by Noah seems to reflect what happened to me; I had an long running transaction (forgot to create indexes, whoops) that made auto vacuum run, and that cleaned up the files from the `pg_xact` folder: https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2546853

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I thought about this issue again and looked at my code to see what I was doing... and now I'm not sure if that reply represents exactly my issue. I'm not creating a transaction, however I'm holding a connection open until the connection is dead, which if it is dead then I get a new transaction from the pool. Maybe JDBC is creating a transaction "behind the scenes"? https://github.com/LorittaBot/Loritta/blob/d9b84bd1edf492bb32ee906e4ac6c58930e358c7/pudding/client/src/main/kotlin/net/perfectdreams/loritta/cinnamon/pudding/utils/PostgreSQLNotificationListener.kt#L28

Comment: I had other long running transactions in the database, but they shouldn't affect the `NOTIFY`/`LISTEN` system, right? They would cause issues if the `LISTEN` transaction was hung and wasn't reading any notifications from the queue... but they are! "The LISTEN/NOTIFY queue stores a transaction id for each notification", but if the `LISTEN` connection is running correctly, then there shouldn't be any notifications pending on the queue... hmmm, hard things to think about.

Comment: You don't have to figure this out theoretically. A look into `pg_stat_activity` will show you which sessions are idle in transaction.

Comment: Tested it and nope, it isn't `idle in transaction`, the notification transaction is just `idle`. I think what should I do is track ALL transactions in that database and check if any transaction gets stuck for a looong time and, if it does, maybe that's the culprit. It is a pain that PostgreSQL does not have any way to track what connections are listening to a channel + how many notifications they received + how many notifications are pending + etc, this would make debugging the issue easier since we could try to figure out when exactly the pending notifications start piling up.